# datetime control to be iframed

Tags: web-part, iframe, datepicker, x-frame

Is there a way to i-frame a SharePoint page containing a datetime control (i.e. a datepicker)?
I have a SharePoint page where I set 
The page is correctly "i-framed" in an external page, but the datepicker gives me again the error "impossible to display this content in a iframe".
What should I do? I tried also to allow X-Frame-Options, but with no success.

thanks,
regards

Comment: In the previous line I meant:  I set <WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" /> but with no success